# Specified child already has a parent error on inflated view

Tags: android, android-layout, view, dialog, android-inflate

Immediate help needed!! The code used to work fine, but after a while I noticed rating doesn`t work anymore and gives "the specified child already has a parent, call removeView() first..." on the`alertDialog.show();` line:

```
///// Rating bar initialising
    Context mContext = ShowActivity.this;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_rate_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

    final RatingBar rating_indicator = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rating_bar_cafe_indicator);
    final float current_rating = (float)mDbHelper.getInt(mRowId, type, RATE_COLUMN);
    rating_indicator.setRating(current_rating);


    rateDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowActivity.this);
    rateDialogBuilder.setView(layout);
    rateDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    rateDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.rate_star_med_on);
    rateDialogBuilder.setTitle("RATE IT!");
    rateDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            rating_indicator.setRating(mDbHelper.getInt(mRowId, type, RATE_COLUMN));
            ((ViewGroup)layout.getParent()).removeView(layout);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    ratingText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rate_text);
    rating = (RatingBar) layout.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar_cafe);
    rating.setRating(current_rating);
    rating.setStepSize(1);
    rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(ShowActivity.this);

    if ((int)current_rating != 0) ratingText.setText("Your rating: " + (int)current_rating); 

    Button rateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_rate); 
    rateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = rateDialogBuilder.create(); 
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });

    //////
```

Strange thing, if I call `removeAllViews()` or `removeView()` just before `alertDialog.show();` it does not crash but opens messed up dialogue where I can see both the rating and the current activity or smth. Also the problem might be somewhere else in the code because this used to work fine, any ideas what should I look for or how to change this to make it work?

Comment: What line is the error pointing to?

Comment: its in the question, alertDialog.show(); gives the error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error you're getting is that you are adding a `View` to a parent after it has already been added to a parent.

Looking at your code, it looks like,

```
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_rate_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
```

adds `custom_rate_dialog` to you `layout_root`. Then, you're adding it to another parent when you do `rateDialogBuilder.setView(layout);`

If you're just trying to inflate that layout to set it as the `View` for the `Dialog` then just do

```
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_rate_dialog, null);
```

Comment: thanks this might be better practice but the problem was i happened to add android:id="@+id/layout_root" somehow to the main activity`s layout xml... stupid me it took 4 hours to notice